# Getting org.junit.runner.RunWith is not an annotation type with Cucumber

Tags: selenium, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to set-up a Selenium + Cucumber project in Java (I'm a beginner with Java) in Intellij. This is my class that uses the Cucumber JUnit runner:

```
package runtest;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions (
        features = "C:\\Users\\my-feature.feature",
)

public class RunTest {

}
```

I'm getting these errors:

```
Error:(8, 1) java: annotation @org.junit.runner.RunWith is missing default values for elements annotationType,<init>
Error:(8, 2) java: org.junit.runner.RunWith is not an annotation type
```

I don't know how to resolve this or what is happening. Please help.

Comment: are you using `pom.xml`

Comment: No, I'm not using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had multiple `RunWith` classes in my project path. After pruning the project tree, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to provide the *absolute path* of the *feature file* if you opt to place it within your project space. The name of the *feature file folder* would be enough.

As an example, if you are having the following structure:

- Package: *Q43966680*
- Class: *Runner*
- Feature File Folder: *q43966680*

Snapshot:

[image: Runner_new]

As per your usecase within `@CucumberOptions` you just need to mention:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options (features="q43966680")

public class RunTest {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's useful, but it doesn't answer my question.